# Can I use a custom animation with ngx-Loading?

Tags: css, angular, ngx-loading

I'm using [ngx-loading](https://github.com/Zak-C/ngx-loading) in my Angular project; but I was wondering if there's a way to use a custom CSS animation instead of the options the package provides; I know that I can use multiple animations with the `ngxLoadingAnimationTypes` config option; but I have my own custom spinner that I'd like to use:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.loader-new {
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  position: fixed;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  top: 40%;
  right: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #1f94ed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.loader-new:after {
  content: "";
  width: 85%;
  height: 85%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 40%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-5%, -5%);
}

.loader-new.moon {
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
}

.loader-new.moon:after {
  display: none;
}


/* Animation for loading Spinner*/

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-new moon"></div>
```

I can't seem to find a way to actually disable the default animation it uses; even setting up a `template` config option does not work since it only inserts it on top of the animation itself.